# How I start the React dropzone with a existing file?

Tags: reactjs, dropzone.js, react-dropzone

I need to render the `react-dropzone` component with an existing file, I already tried to search some ways to do it but all of them are using the dropzone.js and not the component, also found the `getDataTransferItems` prop in the component, but didn't help me too much.

Is there a way to render the component with the file? Any prop or something?

Comment: I could not find any props for this. Just out of curiosity. Why would you need to initiate it with an already a file?

Comment: I'm developing a feature where the user needs to open his person page and see the uploaded file there

Comment: Note: `getDataTransferItems` has been renamed to `getFilesFromEvent` in [v10.0.0](https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone/releases/tag/v10.0.0)